# Why can bash $() set environment variables?

Tags: bash, docker

It is from Docker docs - https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/#install-boot2docker, why can `$()` set environment variables

Display the environment variables for the Docker client.

```
$ boot2docker shellinit
```

To set the environment variables in your shell do the following:

```
$ $(boot2docker shellinit)
```

My question is: why can `$(boot2docker shellinit)` set environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can `$(boot2docker shellinit)` set environment variables?

Look at the following function (but it could be a command or a script):

```
foo() { echo "export a=b"; }
```

This command only does one this: print `export a=b` to standard output:

```
$ foo() { echo "export a=b"; }
$ foo
export a=b
```

Now, a [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) *allows the output of a command to replace the command itself*. So if you run `$(foo)` then Bash will first execute `foo` and then use the output of that command to build a command. In our case, the output being `export a=b`, Bash will execute it:

```
$ declare -p a
bash: declare: a: not found
$ $(foo)
$ declare -p a
declare -x a="b"
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(command)` executes the output of `command`.  So `boot2docker` must output something like:

```
export env1=val1
export env2=val2
....
export envN=valN
```

which shows you the environment variable's values when `boot2docker` is run and sets them when this output is executed.

Comment: This would also export the `export` variable several times, so very likely this is not the output of `boot2docker`. Maybe: `export a=b c=d` instead. Ah funny you get upvoted with some wrong information in your answer, with an answer that comes after mine and doesn't add anything useful, and I don't. Go figure... SO is a funny place `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "the export variable".  `export` is a bash builtin command used to assign and *export* a given NAME to environments of subsequently executed commands.

Comment: Do you really think that your line will run: `export env1=val1` _then_ `export env2=val2`, etc.? the answer is no. Try it yourself: `f() { echo echo hello; echo echo world; }`. This function outputs two separate lines: one is `echo hello`, the second is `echo world`. With your reasoning, `$(f)` would output `hello` and `world` on two separate lines. Yet, `$(f)` output `hello echo world`. Did you overlook word splitting here?

Comment: So your command is exactly equivalent to: `export env1=val2 export env2=val2 export env3=val3 ...`, that is, the builtin `export` with arguments `env1=val1`, `export`, `env2=val2`, `export`, etc. (see, it will have several times the argument `export`), so this will export the variable `export` several times `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf it was upvoted as it clearly describes what is going on. Nobody apart from you took it as a literal answer (note "something like" and the ellipsis). It's pretty poor form to nitpick on other answers like this. Having said that, it probably is worth putting a ";" at the end of the export statements.

Comment: @AdrianMouat No, a `;` will not change anything: `export env1=val1; export env2=val2;` will only make `env1` expand to `val1;` (with a trailing semicolon) and `export env1=val1 ; export env2=val2 ;` will only raise an error: `\`;': not a valid identifier`; that's because the _metacharacters_ have already been parsed when command substitutions (and other expansions) occur. Lots of misconceptions here.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean: foo() { echo "export a=b; export c=d;"; } works for me. Are you missing the word "output" in the text?

Comment: @AdrianMouat and what does `a` expand to? answer: `b;` (with a trailing semicolon). And you'll see that `export` is now a variable marked as exported as you can check with the command `export`. I repeat: lots of misconceptions here.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I did misunderstand. Apologies.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I did misunderstand - I just mucked up the quotes; I don't understand why you think this points to "lots of misconceptions".